# Propagate Identity column as foreign key to child object using Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a Parent and Child table with a one-to-many relationship. One parent can have many children that all reference the Parent by its ParentId. ParentId is a generated identifier.

Parent:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Parent") 
public class Parent implements Serializable 
{ private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name = "ParentId") 
private Integer parentId;

@Column(name = "ParentInfo")
private String parentInfo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Parents",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
private List<Child> children = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Child:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "Child") 
public class Child implements Serializable 
{ private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name = "ChildId") private Integer childId;

@Column(name = "ChildInfo")
private String childInfo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumn(name= "ParentId")
private Parent parent;
```

The Child objects are added to the list in the Parent object before a save is attempted. Since childId is a generated identity and parentId is a foreign key that has yet to be generated, the only field populated is the childInfo.

```
payload.setChildren()
parentRepo.saveAndFlush(payload);
```

There are two Sql statements generated, the statement for Parent works and the identity is generated, the save is successful.

However the Sql generated for the child fails because the parentId in the Child objects is 'null'

```
SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentId', table 'db.Child'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

```
Hibernate: insert into Child (ParentId, ChildInfo) values (?, ?) [37morg.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder[0;39m: binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [null]
```

I was hoping that what would happen is that the ParentId would get generated and then populate the field on the Child objects because of the established one-to-many relationship, but that is not the case. Because the ParentId is generated at the time of insert, there is no way to 'pre-populate' the Child objects with the ParentId.

Is there a way to make this work? I was hoping to only use one .saveAndFlush() to take advantage of the entity relationships. Otherwise I am thinking I will need to insert Parent first, get the generated ParentId and then add it to the Child objects before persisting the list of Child objects.